# Set div background color without using ID

Tags: javascript, html

Is possible change color of background my `div` using JavaScript without using ID? And how?

Html code is:

```
<div class="post" onmouseover="test(this)">
```

JS code is:

```
function test(item){
    alert("Hi :-)");   
}
```

Comment: Why can you not use an ID?  Doing it any other way is pretty limiting.

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any reason why you would need to use the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
function test(item){
  item.style.backgroundColor = "red";  
}
```

Since `item` is the actual div you're triggering this event on you won't need an `ID` to style the element.

A really easy (inline) solution would be the one below.

```html
<div class="post" onmouseover="javascript:style.backgroundColor = 'red';">
    Content blabla
</div>
```

I would personally rather do all of this inside a JS file but hey this works too.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the DOM with JavaScript, but you'll have a better time of it if you're using JQuery. You'll want to invest some time learning about selectors:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp.

You'll be looking for something like:

```
function test(){
   var element = $('div');
}
```

As people have shared in the comments, without a unique identifier, you'll have a rough time, especially as new elements are added to the page.

Comment: Depending on the size of his actual `HTML`, I would not recommend using `jQuery` for simple tasks like this. It can easily be done in plain `JavaScript` and takes 100/200 kb less load.

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld yeah, agreed. I assumed a certain lack of experience from the poster and decided an introduction to JQuery would be appropriate, but you're right, I should have had the consideration you pointed out. :)